# PFQueryTableViewController default Loading view not centered

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, ios8

I have a PFQueryTableViewController that load correctly; however, the default loading view (the "Loading....") is not centered in the view. Has any one experienced this? Any idea why/how this could/might happen? Thanks in advance!